# How to run minify, closure, ngc, uglify etc for an ionic production build app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How do I make sure all the optimisations on my ionic app are triggered in the production build.

Command I run: 
    ionic cordova build android --release --prod

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build --prod --release",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
  },
```

but in build log I see minifycss minifyjs optimisejs are all false. How do I make them run?

```
 ionic:lib:build build options: { '--': [],
  ionic:lib:build   engine: 'cordova',
  ionic:lib:build   platform: 'android',
  ionic:lib:build   project: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   verbose: false,
  ionic:lib:build   type: 'ionic-angular',
  ionic:lib:build   prod: false,
  ionic:lib:build   sourcemaps: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   aot: false,
  ionic:lib:build   minifyjs: false,
  ionic:lib:build   minifycss: false,
  ionic:lib:build   optimizejs: false,
  ionic:lib:build   env: undefined } +0ms
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova build' [ 'android',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '\'--release --prod\'',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--verbose',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--interactive',
  ionic:lib:telemetry   '--color' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:project:ionic-angular:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:project:ionic-angular:build Using ionic:build npm script. +13ms
> npm run ionic:build -- --target cordova --platform android

> yy-app@0.0.1 ionic:build /Users/xx/Workspace/yy
> node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build --prod "--target" "cordova" "--platform" "android"
```